# Jenkins job keeps on running even execute shell build step is completed

Tags: linux, shell, tomcat, jenkins

I'm trying to start the Apache tomcat server using Jenkins shell build step. Shell script working fine and respective tomcat is getting started in Linux box.

But my jenkins job not getting completed still it's showing in running state.

Anyone please suggest how to achieve my job getting completed as soon as tomcat started in respective Linux box

Comment: are you trying to restart the Tomcat after deploying a war ? can you include the command that you are executing to do that ?